# Adding an int to a string c++

Tags: c++, numerics

If I have a string `string foo` and I write `foo += 27`, what gets appended to the string? Is it the character with the ASCII hex value 0x27 or with 0x1b?

Also, when I try `foo += 0`, I get a compilation error saying ambiguous overload of += operator with a string and int. How come I don't get a compilation error with adding non-zero numbers, but I do get an error with zero?

If I first say `int z = 0` and then `foo += z`, I do not get an error. What causes the difference?

Comment: The value `0` used to be the way to say `nullptr`. Still causes confusion on whether you mean a value or a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it the character with the ASCII hex value 0x27 or with 0x1b?

Since you're not writing `foo += 0x27`, apparently it's 0x1b.

When you append 0, the compiler cannot distinguish between the two overloads, one appending a char and another a pointer-to-char. An overload appending an int would be the best match but it's not declared in the basic_string template.

Answer (score 2):

I originally erred when I wrote that the compiler treats `foo + 27` the same as `foo + '\033'` or `foo + '\x1b'`.  (Either of which would be a better way to write the expression.)  The type of a character constant is `int` in C, but `char` in C++.  However, because of the implicit conversion between `char` and `int`, and because there is no more specific `std::basic_string<T>::operator+(int)`, the compiler ends up converting `27` to `'\x1b'` anyway.

C++ originally used `0` as the keyword for a null pointer, so `foo + 0` could mean either `foo + static_cast<const char*>(0)` (more succinctly, `foo + nullptr`) or `foo + '\0'`.  The first is undefined behavior and makes no logical sense, but the compiler doesn’t guess that you must have meant it the other way.

Comment: [The type of a character literal in C++ is `char`](https://godbolt.org/g/wWb3Zq), not `int` (see what the demangled name of the generated function is); implicit conversion (in both directions) means there isn't much backwards incompatibility with C.